# Is the tense correct in "I thought that more time than that had passed."?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, past-perfect, backshifting

Is it pertinent to use pluperfect tense here?

> I thought that more time than that had passed.

Is the sentence grammatically correct?

To give you a context: I had approximated the amount of time that had already passed since a particular event, and then I referred to the calendar to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, perfectly correct — because you are indeed talking about a past event (your thought) and then one that precedes it (the passage of time). Grammatically, if you were to shift the first part of your phrase into the present, the past perfect would then need to shift to the perfect: "I *think* that more time than that *has* passed". In your case, the pluperfect is the only option, just as you used it :)